# How to test on click event for li in chai

Tags: javascript, html, chai

So I am having a list with check boxes and have on click event associated with it.

```
<ul class='abc'>
<li>
<input type='checkbox'>
Element 1
</li>
<li>
<input type='checkbox'>
Element 2
</li>
</ul>
```

And I am dynamically adding a click function to it by:

```
const onclickEvt = (event) => {
  // function

}
And then binding by li.click(onclickEvt);
```

The functionality is running fine. How to test that if checkbox is checked then the click event for li will be fired.

I have tried this but this dosen't seems to be working:

```
context('When any checkbox is checked or unchecked', () => {
  it('should call the li click event', () => {
    $(`ul.abc li`).eq(2).find('input').prop('checked', true);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce((`ul.abc li`).eq(2).click());
  });
});
```

Can anybody suggest how to do this?

Comment: I would recommend not unit testing click events. Instead test the function callback directly.

Comment: Can you provide some code and also is there a way that I can test that somehow checking the check boxes  is binded to li click event anyhow.

Comment: If you're using jquery, you can use `$(target).trigger('click')` to simulate a click on a target element.

Comment: I think this will trigger the click function. Are you somehow saying to spy this function and then check that it has been called or not?

Comment: Yeah. Why not? What are you trying to test?

Comment: I was curious to test the onClick event that does onClick event on clicking the checkbox has been triggered or not